# Dynamically adding content to a tree menu

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to dynamically add elements to a tree menu in jquery?
When I use the append() method to add another (li) 'some code' (/li) to extend my tree menu, the code is added but doesn't become live.
Is there another method I should use instead of append().
Any help is appreciated.
Brett

Comment: .. depends on how you made ***live*** the original elements.. shows us your code..

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on how you attached events in the first place:

To have events attached also to elements created after the DOM is ready you could use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('yourselector').live("click", function(){
         //put what to do after a click event
});
```

Comment: 'you must' is not the right suggestion ;) .. there's another way though => delegate()